# Make .gitignore accept only subtitle related extensions

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

My repository is for subtitles editing only, so I don't want unnecessary files being added to the version control, like images for example, just subtitles and fonts. Will this code work? Is it all I need?

```
*
!.ass
!.sub
!.srt
!.otf
!.ttf
!*/
```

Comment: Mine looks almost the same. Except I have `!*/` as the second item. Not sure if it matters but it may. The ignore list is evaluated in order. Also I allow extension with `!*.xyz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need a `*` before the extension.

```
*
!*/
!*.ass
!*.sub
!*.srt
!*.otf
!*.ttf
```